# Wordpress how to get an array of post meta values from an array of ids?

Tags: arrays, wordpress

The code below produces an array of ids for all the published post types

```
// Test Function
add_action('wp_head', 'testa');
function testa() {
        $city = get_post_meta( 47, 'wpsl_city', true ); // Echos the correct meta for a single id

        $all_post_ids = get_posts(array(
            'fields'          => 'ids',
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type' => 'wpsl_stores',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
                                        )); // Echos a list of ids for CPT

        echo json_encode($all_post_ids);
}
```

How do I produce an array of meta values for 'wpsl_city' instead the post id?

Ex:

- Right now I get [1,2,3]

  - Post ids
- I need [New York, Chicago, Miami]

  - Corresponding post meta values for 'wpsl_city'

Comment: Does your meta value stored as an `array`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate a loop of `$all_post_ids`. so you can get post id to get post meta value. try the below code.

```
// Test Function
add_action( 'wp_head', 'testa' );
function testa() {

    $all_post_ids = get_posts(array(
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'wpsl_stores',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    )); // Echos a list of ids for CPT

    foreach ( $all_post_ids as $key => $post_id ) {
        $city = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpsl_city', true ); // Echos the correct meta for a single id
        echo implode(',', $city); // assume value as array.
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution that worked for me:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'testa');
function testa() {

        $city = array();
        $all_post_ids = get_posts(array(
          'fields'         => 'ids',
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'post_type'      => 'wpsl_stores',
          'post_status'    => 'publish'
        )); // Echos a list of ids for CPT

        foreach ( $all_post_ids as $key => $post_id ) {
            $city[] = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpsl_city', true ); // Echos the correct meta for a single id
          }
        echo json_encode($city);
}
```